# Removing zeros in betwenn a string in java

Tags: regex, string

I want to remove zeros in a String.

> For example,

```
String A = AY000120
```

> then the output should be

`AY120`

so basically any thing between AY and next number which is greater than 0 should be removed. Also, if any zero occurs after a number which is greater than 1 then that zero will not be deleted.

A reg ex will be very useful.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Regex for two consecutive zero's at start of input](//stackoverflow.com/q/41795718)

Comment: You can do this simply just by iterating over the characters in the array.

Answer (score 0):

replace `^(AY)0*([1-9].*)`

by `\1\2`

Or, if you knew your input is in fixed format `AY+(zero or more 0)+(other Numbers)`, you can just:

replace `^AY0*` by `AY`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Java but here is a solution that I wrote in JavaScript. I think regex part should work for you

```
let str = "AY000120"
let result = str.replace(/(0*)(?=[1-9])/g, '');     //AY120
```

post any questions if you still have.

(0*) - looks for any number of 0s  (greedy)
(?=[1-9])   -  positive look ahead to make sure any number other than 0 exists